# Add classic / Lightning name to template folders during selection of email template

Tags: visualforce, email-template, salesforce-classic, lightning-templates

When a user searches for an email template while setting up the E-Mail send option, I want to add a clarification to the user showing if folders and templates are being pulled from classic or lightning templates. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I could not able to pull exact scenario but there is a field called FieldName so I have used that API name and implemented in our code visualforce page as well as apex class query . If anyone knows exactly how to differentiate an template just by saying classic or lightning please let me know.
I just query the FolderName in apex class its a normal thing. Can anyone suggest me where even I can differentiate the template clearly as classic and lightning where it is created from it would be helpful. Thank You.

[image]